# Does Android Studio support all Kotlin features and APIs?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am an Android Developer and have a general Kotlin question.  Does Android Studio support all Kotlin features and APIs?  I am certain that all basic types and operators are fully supported and Android Studio can compile.  Is it safe to also assume that Functions, Lambdas, Coroutines, etc. are fully supported?  For example, when Java 8 support was announced for Android Studio, there was a documentation website explaining which Java 8 features were supported and which were not:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features

But this does not exist for Kotlin.  I'm assuming if it's a line of standard Kotlin code, it will compile in Android Studio, is that correct?

The reason for my question is that I work with a group of Java server (mostly spring boot) and JavaFX developers, and we like to share as much code as possible.  The lack of Java 8 compatibility in Android caused some problems for us.  We're looking to convert most of our code into Kotlin now.  I'd like to assume that all of the standard features:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html

And hopefully all of the coroutines features:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutines-guide.html

Will be fully supported for both let's say an Android app built with Android Studio and a Java desktop app built with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within reason, you control the version of Kotlin that gets used and therefore what features are available.

If you have a Kotlin-enabled Android Studio project, and you look in the top-level `build.gradle` file, you may see code like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'` controls the Kotlin version that you will use for the Kotlin plugin (via the interpolated string in the `classpath` directive), and similarly for the Kotlin runtime dependency in a module's `build.gradle` file.

So, a project with the above code can use Kotlin/JVM features that were supported in Kotlin 1.3.20.

The runtime dependency that we use today is `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version`. The `jdk7` indicates that the runtime does not depend on any Java 8+ stuff that Android lacks.

However, changes in future versions of Kotlin will require you to upgrade the Kotlin version in your project. For example, a project using 1.2.71 might not have access to all Kotlin 1.3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is fully supported by Android and Android Studio and even advertised on the Android website:

> Kotlin is production-ready for your Android app development.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/)

Comment: Yes I think I am wary of terms that Android/Google are using like 'production-ready' and 'first-class support', I am overly worried I think.  The Android website said 'subset of Java 8' when that support was announced, but it appears Kotlin is 'fully supported'.  Thanks!

Comment: @LouMorda I ported a few apps from java to kotlin. Never had any problems! You are good to go :)

Comment: Yeah actually the reason I ask and I should put this in my question is that I work with a group of Java server and JavaFX client developers.  We try to share as much code as possible, so the lack of Java 8 support was a huge disappointment for us.  I'm hoping we can share as much Kotlin code as possible!